# Products vs. Assets

Tags: product, asset

I am designing an Opportunity Management solution for a company, where the company basically sells "Repo Homes". So the scenario is that I as a customer own a Home; I default on my mortgage. The Home is now owned by this company.

So basically, where I am heading to is that how can I track the inventory of "Repo Homes" and use that Inventory to drive my Sales.

1. Should I leverage Products + Price books as I want to definitely use Opportunity Line Items? Once the Oppty is Closed/Won, I would then go ahead and create an Asset record.
2. Should I use the Asset object?

Any comments, thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Products are meant to be items that can be sold more than once - i.e. Light Saber versus Death Star. Assets represent specific items owned by an entity -- typically possessing a serial number

In your use case, the repo homes are really assets as the "serial #" is the house title.

If you want to use Opportunity Line Items, you will need to dynamically maintain a product catalog wherein each Product2 is a specific home.

Perhaps a better solution would be a simple Product catalog:

- Single-family home
- Duplex
- Manufactured house

with standard prices = 0

and when the Opportunity Line Items are added, the user selects a specific asset (the actual home) and assigns a price.

This is only the outline of a solution to get you thinking; not necessarily the definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need the opportunity line items, then yes, do what you need to use those. There's nothing wrong with using a standard pricebook for every product.
2. Using the Asset object would make it easier to see what the company already "sold" in your situation. But I'd also check with your company if they want to keep the opportunity records (and their items) around. If they do, then you won't **need** the Asset (it would be duplicated information and consume your customer's storage unnecessarily).

Comment: Thanks Renato. What if I add to tell you that there will only be one line item and we don't need the Quoting functionality? Will you change your recommendation and suggest to use Assets instead?